# Joins - Difference in condition : Placed to left or right

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, sql-server-2012

In the following two queries, the only difference is the condition is swapped.
 Will it make any performance difference?
Which one is advisable? I have searched over web with no luck. Please help.

First Query :

```
select order_date, order_amount 
 from customers 
 join orders 
    on customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
 where customer_id = 3
```

Second Query :

```
select order_date, order_amount 
 from customers 
 join orders 
    on orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id 
 where customer_id = 3
```

Comment: **NOOOOOOOOOO**

Comment: why don't you compare the execution plans?....but the most likely answer is "no, there won't be a difference"

Comment: No difference whatsoever.  The only difference is in readability - that is, the first one is a bit more readable then the second one.

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: You should be getting an ambiguous column error in the `where` clause. You need to qualify the column `customer_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prdp's comment sums up the answer beautifully. The answer is no. But to further clarify and give you some more info:

SQL Server uses TSQL which is a declarative language.  To steal from [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200319/is-sql-declarative) post, the definition of declarative is:

> Programming paradigm that expresses the desired result of computation
>   without describing the steps to achieve it (also abbreviated with
>   "describe what, not how")

What this basically translates to is that you tell SQL Server what you want returned and provide the logic for things like the joins, and SQL Server will figure out the best way to do it. If it has to rearrange joins, do implicit conversions, it will in order to produce an optimal plan.